# Why does rust say "unconstrained type parameter" whereas it seems to be constrained?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

There are two existing structs `S1` and `S2<T>` and two traits `T1` and `T2<T>`. I want to implement `T2<T>` for `S1`, for all `T` that are `AsRef<S2<T1>>`.

I thought I could write :

```rust
struct S1;
struct S2<T>{t:T}

trait T1 {}
trait T2<T> {}

impl <T: AsRef<S2<T1>>> T2<T> for S1 {}
```

but I get the following error ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a9547fa583278c161daaef8978e5da39)):

> error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn T1 + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time

Of course the size of the type is not known at this point ! I want to create a generic implementation for all types that implement T1. So I tried the following :

```rust
struct S1;
struct S2<T>{t:T}

trait T1 {}
trait T2<T> {}

impl <T,U> T2<T> for S1 
    where T: AsRef<S2<U>>,
          U: T1
{}
```

But this does not compile either, with the following error:

> error[E0207]: the type parameter `U` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates

What is the problem with the code above, and how can it be fixed ?

Comment: The problem is that for some `T` there may be multiple types `U` that satisfy all the constraints, so there could be multiple implementations of `T2<T>` for `S1`. Perhaps `T` should actually be an associated type of `T2`?

Comment: @trentcl I am not sure I understand... `U` only appears in the constraint for `T`. Of course there can be several types that `U` that satisfy the constraints, that's what generics are. But for a given concrete type T, there is a single U: the concrete type parameter of `S2`.

Comment: If `Foo` implements `T1`, and `Bar` implements `T1`, and `Baz` implements *both* `AsRef<S2<Foo>>` *and* `AsRef<S2<Bar>>`, which one does `impl T2<Baz> for S1` use?